# How to get value of "dynamically id" in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, razor

How to get value of "dynamically id" in jQuery?

For example: Razor code:

```
@model ...
...
@{
   int i = 0;
   foreach (var item in Model)
   {
      i = i + 1;
      <tr>
         <td class="check">
            <div tabindex="0" id="a[@i]">print</div>    
      </td>
   </tr>
   }
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#a[1]").keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) { // enter == 13
            $("#a[2]").focus();
        }
    });
</script>
```

"#a[1]","#a[2]" - not work, what can I do?

Comment: Why can't you add a common class to it and bind event for the same?

Comment: where is your element for the keyup event?

Comment: @rob  ????? = a[@i], but how can I write it right??

Comment: generally we look for `enter` key press for textbox or text area. Where are those?

Comment: @Rajaprabhu Further, I would like to give each div - another task ...

Comment: You can use `e.key == "Enter"`, it works just as well and you don't have to memorize the key codes either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like other said, put common class for all shared elements or just binding it with this :

```
// bind only id with a in first words
// but this will problem if exist other element use `a` in front of
$("div[id^=a]").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) { // enter == 13
        hideListShowImg();
    }
});
```

**Updated**

```
$("#a[1]") /* should be ----> */ $("#a\\[1\\]")
```

Comment: very nice @Norlihazmey, but What can I do if I want to give each div a different task?? for example - focus() on another component

Comment: Did't get it, explain

Comment: I fix the Q, look up please